# How do I load a JS blob into the browser to show the file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vue.js

Here's my situation. I'm making a personal file sharing website that consists of the following:

- Vue3 app for the front-end
- Net 5.0 API for the back-end

These are running under two different url's

- share.domain.tld
- api.share.domain.tld

After uploading my result is a url to `api.share.domain.tld/{identifier}` which returns the file.

Not I want to be able to show the file directly in the browser from `share.domain.tld/{identifier}` which is where my vue app runs at.

My first solution was to just use a redirect in the router by using `beforeEnter` and just setting `window.location.href` which works fine when accessing from the browser, however when the `share.domain.tld/{identifier}` url is sent on a app like Discord it will not follow the redirect and is unable to show the preview for files.

If I request the file through axios and create the blob for it, how can I use js to load the filedata into the browser as it would when loading the file from a url and let the browser use it's usual handling for it such as showing images or pdfs but downloading other types of files such as zips?